# Fourier Series of $e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am tying to integrate $a_n= \frac{1}{L} e^x\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{h}\right)dx$ and get the solution in sinh form.  I have gotten the long answer, but cannot figure out how to turn it into sinh.
Can someone help me with the steps?

Comment: Hint: use complex numbers

Comment: if $f(x) = e^{ax}1_{x \in [0,1]}$ then $c_n(f) = \int_0^{1} e^{ax} e^{-2i\pi n x}dx = \left.\frac{e^{(a-2i\pi n)x}}{a-2i\pi n}\right|_0^1 =\frac{1 - e^{a}}{a-2i\pi n}$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2i \pi n x}$ converges pointwise (and uniformly on $[\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$)

Comment: of course I meant $c_n(f)= \frac{e^a-1}{a-2i\pi n}$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For the Fourier series of the function $f(x)=e^x$:
> $$f(x)=\frac{\text{a}_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{a}_\text{n}\cos\left(\text{n}x\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{b}_\text{n}\sin\left(\text{n}x\right)$$

---

1. For $\text{a}_0$ we get:
   $$\text{a}_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^x\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[e^x\right]_{-\pi}^\pi=\frac{e^\pi-e^{-\pi}}{\pi}=\frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}$$
2. For $\text{a}_\text{n}$ we get (using two times integration by parts):
   $$\text{a}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^x\cos(\text{n}x)\space\text{d}x=\frac{2\cos(\text{n}\pi)\sinh(\pi)}{\pi(1+\text{n}^2)}$$
3. For $\text{b}_\text{n}$ we get (using two times integration by parts):
   $$\text{b}_\text{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^x\sin(\text{n}x)\space\text{d}x=\frac{-2\text{n}\cos(\text{n}\pi)\sinh(\pi)}{\pi(1+\text{n}^2)}$$